# Python Tkinter grid not working, button covers up a label after being pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a contact book, but when I press "Remove Contact", the popup message covers the button. Any way to fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("contacts.db")
first_name, last_name, phone_number, a = "","","", ""
c = conn.cursor()

def remove():
    global c, remove_contact, a
    conn = sqlite3.connect("contacts.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        c.execute("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE phone=?",(phone_number.get(),))
    notif = Label(remove_contact, text="Removed Contact")
    notif.grid(row=2, column=0)

def remove_window():
    global first_name, last_name, phone_number, remove_contact, a
    remove_contact = Tk()
    remove_contact.title("Remove Contact")
    remove_contact.geometry("300x150")
    phone_number = Entry(remove_contact, width=30)
    phone_number.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=3)
    labell = Label(remove_contact, text="Phone Number")
    labell.grid(row=0,column=0)
    remove_contact = Button(remove_contact, text="Remove Contact", command=remove)
    remove_contact.grid(row=1,column=0)
    mainloop()
remove_window()
```

Comment: not a good practice what You are doing. first of changing instances and using plain `mainloop()`

Comment: no actually everything is accurate, You should rename Your button variable, to sth like `remove_contact_btn` because as it seems tkinter is trying to grid that label to that button